# Installing Ubuntu Linux on a PS2

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu Linux on a PS2 (model SCPH-50004). I have searched a lot on Google and other search engines, but only found [this video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9wIHJBhugg), and it's not quite what I wanted. I am quite new to Linux so I need help with this. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a PS2? How?

Answer (score 8):

The processor of the PS2, called the "Emotion Engine", is a processor from the MIPS family. Since Ubuntu Linux only supports i386, AMD64, and ARM platforms, you cannot install it on the PS2. You need to look for a distribution that supports the MIPS platform.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to compile Ubuntu for the MIPS family?

Comment: Yes, now I wonder that too, is it possible to build it build it for the MISP processor family. And sorry that I asked in the wrong place before.

Comment: There is a proposition since 27 Dec 2009 on [Ubuntu Brainstorm about porting Ubuntu to MIPS](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/23145/) and it doesn't look like a top priority. Technically speaking: "yes, it is possible"; this can be said as Debian (the distribution Ubuntu is forked from) has a MIPS port. However, it is important to understand that porting a distribution such as Ubuntu to a new platform is not only about providing a unique build. It is also maintaining it over time (i.e. rebuilding packages each time the is a security fix, etc.). Both those operations require lots of efforts...

Comment: Ok, I will try the Debian distrubution for mips then.

Comment: Now, when I was to download the mips Debian port, I saw that the Linux kernel it is using can be downloaded [here](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Main_Page). Couldn't I use that kernel on Ubuntu?